# How to sort out this pending approved and delivered items (Excel)

Tags: excel, sorting

```
#   ITEMS   QTY BRANCH  STATUS  SERIAL #     Items  Total
                                             LADDER  5
1   Ladder  1   REE Approved                    
2   Ladder  1   RPZ Pending                     
3   Ladder  1   GDD Delivered                       
4   Ladder  1   RPV Pending                             
5   Ladder  1   RPQ Pending     
6   Plywood 60  REE Approved
7   Plywood 40  RPQ Pending  

 Pending    Approved    Delivered
 3      1           1
```

What I want is when an item is in pending/active/delivered i want to put it to a new cells and has the same QTY . Then it will sort out how many Items are pending/approved/delivered and which one is pending/approved/delivered

for example

```
Items   Total   Pending Aprroved    Delivered
LADDER  5       3       1           1
Plywood 100     40      60          0
```

I wish you can understand it.. :)
                    Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of unique items, enter the following formula in `Cell G2` and drag/copy down as required

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$8,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($G$1:G1,$B$2:$B$8),0,0),0)),"")
```

Then in `Cell H2`, enter the following formula and drag/copy down as required

```
=SUMIF($B$2:$B$8,G2,$C$2:$C$8)
```

Finally in `Cell I2`, enter below formula

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$8,$B$2:$B$8,$G2,$E$2:$E$8,I$1)
```

Drag/copy down as required and across till `Column K`

See image for reference

[image]

Comment: How about if it will be sort out?

Comment: @C.Pasion - What exactly do you mean by sort out?

Comment: nvm got my answer <3 Thank you!

Comment: @C.Pasion - Could you post your solution so anyone with similar problem could get help.

Comment: I made up the question above. My data is quite complicated actually. I just made it simpler.

Comment: @C.Pasion - Alright, as you've solved your problem it will be better to delete the question or mention somewhere that your problem is resolved so that question do not attract more people.